# Eclipse has decided that it wants to ruin my life. Team/Source options are all greyed out.

Tags: java, eclipse, subclipse

After staying up until 1030AM working on, and completing an assignment, I decided that I would take a short nap before formatting it and submitting it. Needless to say that nap became a 5 hour sleep session.

After waking up, I formatted the code to eclipse google style formatting for java, and proceeded to try and commit the files. After realizing my team options did not even show up when right clicking the project, I closed Eclipse and reopened it... and now all of the Source tab options are greyed out. Is there something wrong with my Subclipse? I just started learning Java in the past couple of weeks, so I'm very unfamiliar with Eclipse =(.

I can't even commmit the files using Terminal. The assignment is due in less than 6 hours. If anyone can point me in teh direction of fixing this, I would be eternally grateful =(.

Comment: if you can't even commit files using terminal this sounds weird. any error message? and btw, which command did you type in the terminal?

Comment: Tons of error messages. 

svn: E155021: This client is too old to work with the working copy at
'/Users/JennySeo/Documents/workspace/207Assignment099' (format 31).
You need to get a newer Subversion client. For more details, see
  http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#working-copy-format-change.

 This happened suddenly.

Comment: Sorry I don't have a solution. I guess you could try to update your subversion client to a recent version and see what happens. Doing a google search I see it's not an unusual error (and the fix is not always immediate).

Comment: Eclipse (mars) decided to grey out source formatting in PHP perspective after I enabled JavaScript Coding in the Action Set Availability for that perspective. This is a very obscure way to tell a user that there's possibly a conflict.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to select the project you were working on in the package explorer, and the options under the Source menu should become available again.

If the one you need is still greyed out, open any source file in that project and check again on the menu.

Comment: =(. Everything is stlll greyed out. What do you mean by opening a source file?

Comment: @Dottori In the package explorer, find a source file that belongs to the project, then double click on that and check again.

Also, is the symbol for the project an open or closed folder? Just wondering.

Answer (score 0):

This won't help OP but maybe others. I just had the same problem and found this question because I googled it but after not finding a solution by googling, I found a solution by trying random things. The shortcut <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + F</kbd> didn't work either (I usually use the shortcut and only went into the context menu after the shortcut didn't do anything).

Formatting the source code worked, I wrote a few more lines, and it didn't work anymore. Even after closing and opening the file, closing and opening Eclipse, it didn't work.

I opened that file directly without it being associated with any project (just wanted to write a 50 lines PHP script in a few minutes). And that seems to have caused the problem.

After creating a project for that 1 file, the options are shown, again.